# Reverse sort array of numbers then delete columns in array Google App Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

If I understand, if have (I get arr dynamically)

`var arr = [7,2,5,1]` and I sort it `arr.Sort()` I get `[1,2,5,7]`

How do I `reverse` sort it so I get `[7,5,2,1]`

```
function DeleteColsInList() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sheet = ss.getSheetByName('ShtName')

  var arr= [7,2,5,1];

 // reverse sort here so I can delete columns in proper order highest to  lowest
  var arrSort =arr.sort()

  for (var i = 0, length = arrSort.length; i < length; i++) {
    Sheet.deleteColumns(arrSort[i]);
   }
  }
```

UpDated:

```
function DeleteColsInList() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sheet = ss.getSheetByName('ShtName')

  var arr= [7,2,5,1];

 // reverse sort here so I can delete columns in proper order highest to  lowest
  arr.Reverse()

  for (var i = 0, length = arrSort.length; i < length; i++) {
    Sheet.deleteColumns(arr[i] + 1);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Can you not sort your array and then `arr.reverse()`?

Comment: I searched but did not find `reverse()`. Thanks

Comment: I edited the function it now deletes properly with the addition of reverse()  also `Sheet.deleteColumns(arrSort[i])` needed to be `Sheet.deleteColumns(arrSort[i] + 1)`.  I have to say Google sheets sarting at `0` instead of `one` like I am use to is messing me up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably do this:

```
var arrSort =arr.sort();
arrSort.reverse();
```

I think you can even chain them:

```
var arrSort = arr.sort().reverse();
```

Per the comments, even that's more verbose than necessary. You can just do

```
arr.sort().reverse()
```

on your original array object.

*(h/t to [red red wine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/79865))*

Comment: The [sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts in place, and reverse also operates in place. So, `arr.sort().reverse();` is all that's needed; assigning to arrSort just creates another name for the same thing (with `arr` itself also being sorted and reversed). cc @Tim

Comment: So @AI E. @red red wine, I ended up with, and it appears to work, simply, `arrSort = arr.Reverse()` no `Sort()` necessary?

Comment: @Tim First of all, there is no Reverse method (and no Sort). There are reverse and sort. Second, sort is necessary if you want to sort the array. If you don't want to sort it, it's not necessary. Lastly, as I remarked above, these methods modify the object on which they act. Writing `arr.sort()` results in `arr` itself being sorted. There is not need to introduce arrSort into the picture.